# Matlab Subplot of symbolic functions (with quite different range and domain), Want to achieve same axis scale for every subplot

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure, symbolic-math

I have 3 subplots in Matlab, each curve has quite different domain and range. I wish to have the same scale of (1 unit = 1 cm of paper) in  x and y axes of all the graphs.

I cannot use linkprop for xlim or ylim, as the domain and range is quite different, and the complete graphs do not appear.

Kindly give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I'm proud of this, but it does seem to work!

```
x1=0:.1:1;
x2=50:1:90;
x3=0.043:0.001:0.089;
y1=sin(x1);
y2=x2.^2;
y3=-x3;

r=max([max(y3)-min(y3) max(y2)-min(y2) max(y1)-min(y1)]);
d=max([max(x3)-min(x3) max(x2)-min(x2) max(x1)-min(x1)]);
k=max(r,d);

subplot(1,3,1)
plot(x1,y1)
axis([min(x1)-(k-max(x1)+min(x1))/2 max(x1)+(k-max(x1)+min(x1))/2 ...
    min(y1)-(k-max(y1)+min(y1))/2 max(y1)+(k-max(y1)+min(y1))/2])
subplot(1,3,2)
plot(x2,y2)
axis([min(x2)-(k-max(x2)+min(x2))/2 max(x2)+(k-max(x2)+min(x2))/2 ...
    min(y2)-(k-max(y2)+min(y2))/2 max(y2)+(k-max(y2)+min(y2))/2])
subplot(1,3,3)
plot(x3,y3)
axis([min(x3)-(k-max(x3)+min(x3))/2 max(x3)+(k-max(x3)+min(x3))/2 ...
    min(y3)-(k-max(y3)+min(y3))/2 max(y3)+(k-max(y3)+min(y3))/2])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and I am sorry I was unable to respond timely due to some constraints. The graph for (x1 y1) and (x3 y3) is almost invisible; what I wish is that the scale for all x and y axes of all subplot should remain the same (in your case scale of x and y axes of each graph is different). Also, the range and domain should adjust such that the graph is visible. Page size is not a constraint for me, I can use A0 sheet also.

Comment: I am trying to plot symbolic function using ezplot; whose domain and range is not known to me, so I am unable to use your technique. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you just do 3 separate plots and print them at different scales?

Comment: The comparison will lose its meaning. Let me tell my application: In the first graph we have curve fitted an ellipse in general 2nd order polynomial in x and y. In the 2nd graph, the ellipse is rotated to eliminate xy term. In the 3rd graph the ellipse is translated with its centre at origin of coordinate system. So, every x and y axis should have same scale as it is the same ellipse.

Comment: In my case the scale of all the axes were identical. The fact that two plots are almost invisible is because the domains are so different, but one unit in each plot is the same amount of change in x or y.

Comment: in your case, y1 y2 y3 have same scale, x1 x2 and x3 have same scale , but x and y have different scale. What I want is: let the plots occupy different area in the paper, but they should represent the curve clearly with same scale for all x axes and y axes and also for a particular x axis and y axis.